# Combining Fields from user input content fragment in grapgql

Tags: graphql, aem

There are 2 tag fields in my content fragment model lets assume the names as tag1 and tag2. User creates a content fragment and selects the desired tag values. But I want to take these 2 values and combine them with an underscore. is there any command that permits this in graphql or is there any other solution to this. can I make a separate field for it in crx/de and then obtain it's value in it. if yes then what should be the parameters for this or should use some javascript in it. please help.

I tried to concat the fields in graphql only but it is not working
desired output:- tag1_tag2 :--- want this value for filtering

Comment: GraphQL doesn't have any sort of expression language, or any sort of way to combine or reuse result values.  You'd either need to combine the values on the client (based on the results of the two fields) or the server (exposing the result as a new GraphQL field); you can't do it only in the query.